# помогите с запросом mysql (выбор пользователей которые делали заказ более 200 дней назад)

Tags: mysql, select

Всем привет!
Не могу разобраться, помогите пожалуйста
Нужно выбрать пользователей которые делали заказ более 200 дней назад

```
SELECT u.user,(SELECT MAX(date) FROM `shop_orders` WHERE user = u.user) AS lastorder FROM `users` as u
WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(lastorder) > 200
```

или

```
SELECT u.user,MAX(s.date) as lastorder FROM `users` as u
LEFT JOIN `shop_orders` as s ON s.user = u.user 
WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(lastorder) > 200
```

в обоих случаях пишет Unknown column 'lastorder' in 'where clause'
Как работать с полученным lastorder и почему он его не видит?

Comment: *Нужно выбрать пользователей которые делали заказ более 200 дней назад* Вы пишете запросы совсем для другой задачи, а именно "которые **последний раз** делали заказ более 200 дней назад". Определитесь, что же именно Вам необходимо получить.

Comment: Да, именно "которые последний раз делали заказ более 200 дней назад"

Answer (score 0):

для условий с даными полученными из подзапросов используется конструкция HAVING

попробуйте так

SELECT u.user,(SELECT MAX(date) FROM `shop_orders` WHERE user = u.user) AS lastorder FROM `users` as u
 HAVING TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(lastorder) > 200

Comment: Подзапрос тут нафиг не нужен.

Comment: Akina, предложите свой вариант если знаете как лучше

Comment: sterx, SELECT COUNT(u.user) as count,(SELECT MAX(date) FROM shop_orders WHERE user = u.user) AS lastorder FROM users as u HAVING TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(lastorder) > 200 - с COUNT(u.user) не работает